# Mocha + Chai unit test case giving Timeout of 2000ms exceeded error with setTimeout/promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write unit test case for certain scenario where I return promise once certain event completes then only resolve happens.

But with async/await I'm getting timeout error.

Below is example snippet.

Some test method:

```
const createDB = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(10);
        },1000);
 })}
```

Unit test

```
describe('fileName.spec', () => {
    it('should create record in DB', async () => {
        const data = await createDB();
        assert.equal(data, 10);
    });
});
```

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Note : Even if I increase time for test i.e. 10000ms error says Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Tried including done() no success.

Can someone please help thanks.

Comment: There's no mistake. Make sure the code is exactly as you posted. "But with async/await I'm getting timeout error" - does it disappear when async is removed in this test?

Comment: Yeah even with createDB.then((res) => someOperation(res)) I See same error, After removing async/await

Comment: @EstusFlask Also if I use await or wait for response no error

Comment: Please, clarify the last comment. Currently it looks like the error occurs in another test

Comment: So Basically in below code if I remove await it goes to assert.equal, no timeout error, but as expected test case fail as data is not equals to 10 
describe('fileName.spec', () => {
    it('should create record in DB', async () => {
        const data = createDB();
        assert.equal(data, 10);
    });
});

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is needed for your case. I see two possibilities, either createDB implementation is not what you expect for some reason, or this error comes from another test, this doesn't happen if you don't wait and a test suit ends too quick. Please, update the question, it shouldn't have irrelevant tags. It's either Jest or Mocha, not both

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for pointing I have update tag it mocha+chai

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask for suggestion actually other testCase was causing issue
as it was using useFakeTimers in wrong way, Although I need to debug why useFakeTimers caused being in other test.